Deflecting a lunar mass with consecutive nuclear explosions
I'm looking for help in determining the amount of deflection an object with a mass of roughly $7\times10^{22} \,\text{kg}$ (a lunar mass) needs from colliding with a planet. Let's stipulate that the lunar mass is travelling at $42 \,\text{km}/\text{s}$ towards our unnamed planet.
I figure trying to change the course of the lunar mass will be easier than knocking a planet out of its orbit around its host star.
Let's be more specific: I want to use nuclear explosives (say 10 megatons each of explosive power) to go off in a sequential line between the lunar mass and the planet, to produce a shockwave that will change the trajectory of the lunar mass, and not hit the planet it is careening towards at $42 \,\text{km}/\text{s}$.
Could this approach work to stop the cataclysmic collision between the lunar mass and the planet it is set to hit in $105 \,\text{hours}$? Is the number of nuclear explosions needed within a practical quantity (say a few hundred) to produce the needed shockwave?
I mention "shockwave" since I'm not looking to detonate the nuclear charges on the lunar mass, but between the lunar mass and the planet it is set to collide with, that way a cumulative effect of explosions can deflect the lunar mass from its collision course.

Are we just supposed to know what "Operation Shockwave" is?

@hft Oh, Operation Shockwave is the thought experiment above, using spaced nuclear charges to produce a shockwave, deflecting the 7 x 10²² kg object off course, so it won't collide with the planet it is going to crash into.

Scott Manley is your guy. In Smashing An Asteroid All The Way Through Planet Earth!. he uses SpaceSim for the simulations. You might check out his Kerbal Space Program tutorials to see how much deflection you would need for an incoming object to avoid the Earth. I don't think his Going Nuclear series will help you find the force, but you might check them.

A 10 megaton bomb is tiny relative to the KE & momentum of your rogue moon. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TNT_equivalent#Examples Pity you can't intercept it at a larger distance...

This could not work. Not even close.
Let's start by calculating what has to be accomplished. Assume the body is the same size as the moon and is aimed at the center of the earth. It therefore needs to be deflected by about 8000 km to completely miss. (Here I am ignoring any effects of gravity that might cause it to bend back towards the earth.) You have 105 hours, which is $3.8 \times 10^5$ seconds, to do this. So if you could give it a sideways velocity of 21 m/s at the beginning of the 105 hours, it would just miss. The mass of the object is $7 \times 10^{22}\ \mathrm{kg}$ so the total momentum required is $1.4 \times 10^{24}\ \mathrm{kg\ m/s}$. If you are not able to change the velocity at the beginning of the time window, things only get worse. So this is the best case scenario.
What you would ideally like to do is use the available energy to launch a massive object, either smashing it into the moon, or launching it from the moon's surface. There is little mass available in space to smash into the moon, so the shockwave approach is not going to work. It's probably best to do it the other way around. Let's assume you manage to get the nuclear bombs buried under the lunar surface so you can launch some part of the moon into space.
You are now limited by the fact that the moon has gravity. If you launch something too slowly, it will fall back down. To avoid that, you have to initially give your object a velocity of at least 2400 m/s, the lunar escape velocity. This in turn limits the mass of the object you can launch with the available energy. If you launch very large objects, they will not escape, or will escape without enough momentum to matter. If you launch very small objects, you waste energy.
Maximizing the momentum transfer is therefore an optimization problem. We want to find a mass $m$ to launch such that $m(v-2400\ \mathrm{m/s})$ is maximized, where $v = \sqrt{2E/m}$. This is not too hard to solve; the maximum possible momentum transfer is $E/(4800\ \mathrm{m/s})$ (which occurs when you launch objects with exactly twice the escape velocity).
Each nuclear bomb has an energy of $4.2\times 10^{16}\ \mathrm{J}$ which, if converted 100% efficiently to mechanical energy and used to launch the optimal mass, can provide a change in momentum of $8.75 \times 10^{12}\ \mathrm{kg\ m/s}$. And therefore, in this configuration, a total of $1.6 \times 10^{11}$ 10-megaton nuclear bombs are needed to impart the required momentum to the moon.
